# Is there any way to edit my doc with googleDocs editor?

Tags: editor, google-docs

I have a php websites user can upload their word documents all documents stored on my website. i would like make user can edit the document with google document editor. so how can i use the googleDoc editor or is there any editor already exist to edit doc?

Answer (score 0):

Google docs is accessible trough google drive which has an API, so you can make API calls that save the document and then open it on google docs

https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: Accessible only which is stored on google drive. not external file. documents stored on my website.